# How to increase Ubuntu font and icon size?

Tags: unity, virtualbox, icons, fonts

I installed VirtualBox (version 5.2.18) on my Windows 10 laptop.

There I am running Ubuntu 18.04, the OS in general looks small. I've tried changing resolution but it didn't work as I expected. Then I used Unity Tweak Tools to change font size and it sort of work for some programs but not all and anyways the icons still look pretty small.

Here is a photo of how it looks

Screenshot of my Desktop
[image: screenshot of my desktop]

How can I make it look bigger in general?

Comment: @JustHalf "Unity Tweak Tool" or "Gnome-Tweaks"?